# Finding value of an integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, complex-analysis

I was trying to find $\int_{0}^{1}{\sqrt{t^4+t^2+1}}dt$.

I’ve tried substitution $u=\tan x$  but end with unpleasant integral. If someone have an idea, even complex integration, I’ll take

Comment: Only a numerical solution is possible.

Comment: By numerical do you mean approximative solution???

Comment: Yes that is what i mean

Comment: Can you provide a numerical one.

Comment: See here $$1/3\,{\frac {2\,i{\it EllipticF} \left( 1/2+i/2\sqrt {3},1/2+i/2\sqrt 
{3} \right) \sqrt {3}-\sqrt {3}+3\,i+2\,{\it EllipticE} \left( 1/2+i/2
\sqrt {3},1/2+i/2\sqrt {3} \right) }{-1+i\sqrt {3}}}
$$

Comment: Yes, it's an elliptic integral. Nevertheless, an explicit expression can sometimes be more useful than brute-forcing with numerical integration, since there are known fast algorithms for computing elliptic integrals.